# Is it possible to use the Free Tier of AWS DynamoDB On Demand?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The [DynamoDB On Demand Free Tier documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/#DynamoDB_free_tier) describes the free tier as including

> - 25 GB of data storage
> - 2.5 million stream read requests from DynamoDB Streams
> - 1 GB of data transfer out, aggregated across AWS services

Since this includes no [read or write requests](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/#.E2.80.A2_Read_and_write_requests), is there any way to actually use DynamoDB on demand (use as in read or write to the DB) in the free tier?

Does the free tier include some read and write requests and the documentation doesn't mention them?

Is the least you can spend on DynamoDB On-Demand $1.50 ($1.25 + $0.25) per month if you actually want to read and write to your DB?

Note : This is distinct from the [DynamoDB Provisioned Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/) which works differently and appears to have a free tier that you can actually use.

Answer (score 2):

Seems on-demand mode is not free tier eligible. [This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html) says

> Amazon DynamoDB has two read/write capacity modes for processing reads and writes on your tables:
>
> - On-demand
> - Provisioned (default, free-tier eligible)

Which implies that On-demand is not free-tier eligible